# Can I use cp to backup and restore Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space

On the same physical machine, the partitions of / and /home are both not large enough. I cannot extend the two partitions directly, since they are the last two partitions. I deleted the two partitions and allocated two larger partions.

Can I use `cp` to backup the two partitions and then recover them to the new / and /home? I use a USB disk to store and restore the backup file.

Comment: Yes you can, but there are better backup utilities.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this.

If you wish to use cp, use the `-R` flag for recursive copy and `-p` to preserve file attributes (mode, ownership, timestamps)

Answer (score 2):

The filesystem on your USB drive should be a Unix filesystem so you'll keep all your files attribute (permissions, owner, group, ...).

Then the `cp` command has an `--archive (-a)` option which will preserve the attributes. Ideally, you can add the `--one-file-system (-x)` option so you won't backup other filesystems like `/proc`, `/sys`, or others.

```
shell# cp --archive --one-file-system /home <DESTINATION>
shell# cp --archive --one-file-system / <DESTINATION>
```

There you are. For restoration you'll do:

```
shell# cp --archive <ROOT_BACKUP>/* /
shell# cp --archive <HOME_BACKUP>/* /home
```

Comment: Do not restore on your current "/". Boot from a live distro, mount the local drive to "/mnt/local_driver", and restore there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but with a word of caution

- Use -p (Otherwise permissions will mess things up)
- Use -f for safety
- You may require to update grub (sudo update-grub) to get things working after you copy stuff back. (This will be the case if you are using the backed up grub.cfg file for boot)

**Alternative:** You could use Disk Utilities like [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) (sudo apt-get install gparted) to move partitions too. Just empty some space before / & /home and ask GParted to extend backwards (Ref: [GParted Manual Page](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-move-partition))

Comment: gparted and other alternatives are nice, but cannot yet deal with btrfs , however.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a dedicated Live distro.

The tools that I usually use for these purposes are [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) and [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/), which are available both stand-alone or included in specialized distros like [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/).

I suggest you to use the latter option because along Clonezilla and Gparted has a lot of other useful disk and system maintenance tools.